# Arcgis runtime for wpf - clusterer memory leak

Tags: wpf, arcgis, esri

I have application with ArcGIS Runtime for WPF. I use Clusterer to my objects in GraphicsLayer, I'm trying FlareClusterer and CustomClusterer. Every clusterer rebuild increases used RAM.

I've tried calling:

```
GC.Collect();    
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

but this doesn't help.

Does anyone know of a solution for this problem?

P.S. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: ask on gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

`GC.Collect();` won't help if objects can't be collected. I would suggest profiling your app. Use ANTS, it's free for 2 weeks. It will show you zombie leftover objects. 
A quick check is to go through you code and look for all event subscriptions. Every += should have -= (unless it's anonymous lambda that does work right in the same spot) Make sure to unsubscribe before you release the object. That's a common mistake especially when clearing collections (collection is clear, but the object that it used to have will remain.
There lots of other things, but ANTS I think is the first quick and easy test.